# The difference between "adatto" and "giusto"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I have found the following sentences:

> Questi non sono vestiti adatti per sciare.
>
> Questa è la palla adatta per giocare a calcio.
>
> Questo tavolo non è della grandezza giusta per quest'uomo.

How can you distinguish `addato` and `giusto` to modify a noun? In other words, why don't you say `Questi non sono vestiti giusti per sciare.` or `Questo tavolo non è della grandezza adatta per quest'uomo.`?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @I.M. Sorry I'm not and I added my comment on the answer. I understand its rule; don't worry.

Answer (score 5):

"Adatto/i" mean appropriate whereas giusto means correct. So "adatto" is used when something is fit for a purpose while "giusto" when something is the correct choice for a purpose. The meaning is almost the same, but if you translate into English your sample phrases using my explanation you might see the difference:

> These are not appropriate clothes for skiing.
>
> These are not the right clothes for skiing.
>
> This is an appropriate ball for playing soccer.
>
> This is the right ball for playing soccer.
>
> This table is not the appropriate height for this man.
>
> This table is not the correct height for this man.

So the words were chosen to express a particular nuance in meaning.

Comment: Hmm... I can't get it. Your explanation contrasts `appropriate` and `correct`, but your sample sentences seem to contrast `right` and `correct`. Maybe is it typo?